# biblatex: only use ibid in certain situations

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

`biblatex` has the option of using "ibid" in citations with the `authoryear-ibid` option. With this option activated, my pdf output contains both:

**(I)** `(ibid.)`; and

**(II)** `John (ibid)`.

I would like to keep (I) but not (II) -- i.e., I would like `biblatex` to print `John (2000)` but not `John (ibid)`. Does anyone know how to do that?

(Here is another way of formulating my question if you use `natbib=true`: can I activate the use of ibid with `\citep` but not with `\citet`?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `\ifciteibid` test must be removed from the `textcite` bibmacro. For convenience, I use the [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package to selectively change the bibmacro's definition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}{%
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
      {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}}
}{%
      {\iffieldundef{labelyear}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:label}}
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
}{}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{A01}.

As was shown in \citet{A01}~\dots

Some more text \citep{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Here are the modifications necessary for the `authoryear-icomp` style (which uses  a different implementation of `textcite`):

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}{%
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
       \setunit{%
         \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
         \addspace\bibopenparen}%
       \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
         {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
         {}%
       \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
         {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
}{%
          {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
       \setunit{%
         \global\booltrue{cbx:parens}%
         \addspace\bibopenparen}%
       \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
         {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
         {}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}
}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{textcite}{%
             {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}%
}{%
             {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}%
}{}{}
```

Comment: that works great with `citestyle=authoryear-ibid`. But I've noticed that this solution does not work with `authoryear-icomp` style and I don't understand why that happens. Do you know how I can fix this?